# WordPress conflicting with PageLines

Tags: wordpress, pagelines, wordpress-5.5

I have noticed that I am unable to edit my wordpress pages via PageLines5 after update to WP 5.5.

These are the errors in my site when try to edit a page:

`Uncaught ReferenceError: wp is not defined at color-picker.min.js:2`

`Uncaught TypeError: a(...).wpColorPicker is not a function at editing.js:5`

The Plugin "Enable jQuery Migrate Helper" didn't help me.

Comment: Maybe incompatible/clashing jQuery versions? But there really isn't enough information here to be able to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after wordress update, Page editor (Pagelines framework) can't edit because `a(...).wpColorPicker is not a function at editing.js` bloc script

solution :
look at the file edit.js in wp-content/plugins/pl-platform/engine/ui/js/edit.js
after that unminify a file, finally make edit
before :

```
.each(function () {
a(this)
    .wpColorPicker({
        change: function (b, c) {
            var d = a(this);
            d.val(d.iris("color")).trigger("keyup");
            var e = _.debounce(
                function () {
                    d.trigger("blur");
                },
                300,
                { leading: !1 }
            );
            e();
        },
    })
    .addClass("is-ready loaded");
})
...
```

})

instead of (adding ...hasOwnProperty('wpColorPicker')

```
.each(function () {
if(a(this).hasOwnProperty('wpColorPicker')) {
    a(this)
        .wpColorPicker({
            change: function (b, c) {
                var d = a(this);
                d.val(d.iris("color")).trigger("keyup");
                var e = _.debounce(
                    function () {
                        d.trigger("blur");
                    },
                    300,
                    { leading: !1 }
                );
                e();
            },
        })
        .addClass("is-ready loaded");
    }
})
...
```

})

refresh your page make sure your file is updated, i suggest to delete cache browser done.
it work for me